# Ag-grid Master Detail not allowing expanding row

Tags: javascript, master-detail, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am attempting to implement some sort of master detail functionality with Ag-grid. I want a row to be expandable as the master detail suggests but do not want  a nested table in the detail cell ( just some custom html).

I am having trouble setting this up and cannot seem to even get my grid to allow for expanding rows. I am using aurelia but have created a simple plunkr that show my setup.

Note that my detailCellRendererParams only contains a template, since I do not want a table. In grid options I have set ***masterDetail: true***.

```
var detailCellRendererParams = {
      template: function(params) {
        var personName = params.data.name;
        return (
          '<div style="height: 100%; background-color: #EDF6FF; padding: 20px; box-sizing: border-box;">' +
          '  <div style="height: 10%;">Want some html template in here with no data table ' +

          "</div>" +
          '  <div ref="eDetailGrid" style="height: 90%;"></div>' +
          "</div>"
        );
      }
    };

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    enableColResize: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    masterDetail: true,
    detailCellRendererParams: detailCellRendererParams
};
```

Please could you take a loot at my plunkr and try to identify what I am missing in order to get the expandable details cell for each row.

Thanks

https://plnkr.co/edit/12COBiJpn6eXPo71ojmE?p=preview

Comment: in your plunkr you reference ag-grid version 2.3.5 (not enterprise) which is really old. Master/detail is only available from v14.2 on

Answer (score 0):

Master/Detail is an enterprise feature. You need to pay for that feature if you want to use the `masterDetail` `gridOptions` parameter. You would also need to pull in the enterprise version of the `ag-grid.js` file.

Comment: Im sorry I didnt mention that I have an enterprise license. and am importing the enterprise version in aurelia via : 
import "ag-grid-enterprise/main";

Comment: -1 one because this is not correct. You can still use enterprise features abut until you purchase the enterprise license you will have the watermark in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is part of enterprise edition so you need to add import in your application for `ag-grid-enterprise` as follows:

In `pollyfills.ts` add import for application imports section

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
```